# dplyr filter: Get rows with minimum of variable, but only the first if multiple minima

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to make a grouped filter using `dplyr`, in a way that within each group only that row is returned which has the minimum value of variable `x`.

My problem is: As expected, in the case of multiple minima *all* rows with the minimum value are returned. But in my case, **I only want the first row** if multiple minima are present.

Here's an example:

```
df <- data.frame(
A=c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
x=c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5),
y=rnorm(9)
)

library(dplyr)
df.g <- group_by(df, A)
filter(df.g, x == min(x))
```

As expected, all minima are returned:

```
Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
Groups: A

  A x           y
1 A 1 -1.04584335
2 A 1  0.97949399
3 B 2  0.79600971
4 C 5 -0.08655151
5 C 5  0.16649962
6 C 5 -0.05948012
```

With ddply, I would have approach the task that way:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, .(A), function(z) {
    z[z$x == min(z$x), ][1, ]
})
```

... which works:

```
  A x           y
1 A 1 -1.04584335
2 B 2  0.79600971
3 C 5 -0.08655151
```

**Q: Is there a way to approach this in dplyr?** (For speed reasons)

Comment: `filter(df.g, rank(x) == 1)` ?

Comment: Thanks. I knew there would be an easy solution ;-)

Comment: @FelixS, does `rank(x)==1` give the desired results?

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, it requires `ties=first` argument. FelixS, if you're going for speed, `rank` is a bad idea - it's computationally more demanding than `min` (or) `which.min`.

Comment: Actually you probably want `min_rank()`. @Arun: dplyr provides an internal implementation of `min_rank()` that should be plenty fast enough.

Comment: @hadley, 1) I don't think `min_rank` helps here. He needs the first min value (look at `plyr` solution). 2) In whatever programming language you write, the algorithmic complexity of `rank` (ties=min, max, first etc..) will be bigger than just computing `min`.

Comment: @arun premature optimisation is ...

Comment: @hadley, not following you.

Comment: @Arun: True, only `rank(x, ties.method="first")==1` works, as min and min_rank do not differentiate between multiple minima.

Comment: @FelixS, right. But that's quite expensive (because it has to sort all values for every group). You should be using `which.min`. But I don't know of a `dplyr` solution. A `plyr` case would be: `ddply(df, .(A), function(z) z[which.min(z$x), ])`

Comment: @Arun it's assuming that an O(n lg n) algorithm will perform significantly worse that an O(n) algorithm without further information about the domain

Comment: Sorry, I was actually thinking of `row_number()` - it's the equivalent of `rank(ties = "first")` but is be implemented more efficiently in C++.

Comment: @hadley, I still don't see how that makes you consider `which.min` to be premature optimisation. AFAIK it's a natural choice, reads well, easy to understand, fast as it happens to be O(n) too.

Comment: With the time I saved finding this answer, I benchmarked the `which.min()` and `rank()` solutions. For a 40k x 24 data table, these take about 130 vs 240 ms on my machine.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just for completeness: Here's the final `dplyr` solution, derived from the comments of @hadley and @Arun:

```
library(dplyr)
df.g <- group_by(df, A)
filter(df.g, rank(x, ties.method="first")==1)
```

Answer (score 123):

#### Update

With dplyr >= 0.3 you can use the `slice` function in combination with `which.min`, which would be my favorite approach for this task:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% slice(which.min(x))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
#Groups: A
#
#  A x          y
#1 A 1  0.2979772
#2 B 2 -1.1265265
#3 C 5 -1.1952004
```

---

#### Original answer

For the sample data, it is also possible to use two `filter` after each other:

```
group_by(df, A) %>% 
  filter(x == min(x)) %>% 
  filter(1:n() == 1)
```

Comment: I find `do(head)` easier to read, `df %>% group_by(A) %>% filter(x == min(x)) %>% do(head(.,1))`

Comment: @baptiste that looks nice indeed (however, when i run it, i get an error message `Error: expecting a single value`) - do you know why?

Comment: not sure, maybe we're using a different version; I have `dplyr_0.2, magrittr_1.0.0`

Comment: Ok, so the problem is I'm still running dplyr 0.1.3. Thx

Comment: I’d prefer being able to use `top_n` here but due to ties this method is probably the clear winner — definitely in terms of performance (when compared to `arrange %>% slice`).

Comment: In dplyr version 1.0.2, there is ```slice_max()``` which lets you select rows with highest or lowest values of a variable. Hence, this answer can be abbreviated as:
```df %>% group_by(A) %>% slice_max(x)```

Answer (score 16):

For what it's worth, here's a `data.table` solution, to those who may be interested:

```
# approach with setting keys
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt, A,x)
dt[J(unique(A)), mult="first"]

# without using keys
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[dt[, .I[which.min(x)], by=A]$V1]
```

Answer (score 7):

The `dplyr` package offers the `slice_min()` function, which does the job with the argument `with_ties = FALSE`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  slice_min(x, with_ties = FALSE)
```

Output :

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
A         x      y
<fct> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1  0.273
2 B         2 -0.462
3 C         5  1.08
```

Answer (score 6):

This can be accomplished by using `row_number` combined with `group_by`. `row_number` handles ties by assigning a rank not only by the value but also by the relative order within the vector. To get the first row of each group with the minimum value of `x`:

```
df.g <- group_by(df, A)
filter(df.g, row_number(x) == 1)
```

For more information see the dplyr [vignette on window functions](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/window-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

In case you are looking to filter the minima of x and then the minima of y. An intuitive way of do it is just using filtering functions:

```
> df
  A x            y
1 A 1  1.856368296
2 A 1 -0.298284187
3 A 2  0.800047796
4 B 2  0.107289719
5 B 3  0.641819999
6 B 4  0.650542284
7 C 5  0.422465687
8 C 5  0.009819306
9 C 5 -0.482082635  

df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
       filter(x == min(x), y == min(y))
 
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
  A         x      y
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1 -0.298
2 B         2  0.107
3 C         5 -0.482
```

This code will filter the minima of x and y.

Also you can do a double filter
that looks even more readable:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  filter(x == min(x)) %>%
  filter(y == min(y))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   A [3]
  A         x      y
  <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
1 A         1 -0.298
2 B         2  0.107
3 C         5 -0.482
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- data.frame(a = rep(1:2, each = 10), b = rnorm(20))
x <- dplyr::arrange(x, a, b)
dplyr::filter(x, !duplicated(a))
```

Result:

```
  a          b
1 1 -0.8356286
2 2 -2.2146999
```

Could also be easily adapted for getting the row in each group with maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

I like sqldf for its simplicity..

```
sqldf("select A,min(X),y from 'df.g' group by A")
```

Output:

```
A min(X)          y

1 A      1 -1.4836989

2 B      2  0.3755771

3 C      5  0.9284441
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, here's the `base R` answer:

```r
df[with(df, ave(x, A, FUN = \(x) rank(x, ties.method = "first")) == 1), ]

#  A x          y
#1 A 1  0.1076158
#4 B 2 -1.3909084
#7 C 5  0.3511618
```