# How to drop unused levels after filtering by factor?

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is an example that was taken from [a fellow SO member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24679950).

```
# define a %not% to be the opposite of %in%
library(dplyr)
# data
f <- c("a","a","a","b","b","c")
s <- c("fall","spring","other", "fall", "other", "other")
v <- c(3,5,1,4,5,2)
(dat0 <- data.frame(f, s, v))
#  f      s v
#1 a   fall 3
#2 a spring 5
#3 a  other 1
#4 b   fall 4
#5 b  other 5
#6 c  other 2
(sp.tmp <- filter(dat0, s == "spring"))
#  f      s v
#1 a spring 5
(str(sp.tmp))
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ f: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1
# $ s: Factor w/ 3 levels "fall","other",..: 3
# $ v: num 5
```

The df resulting from `filter()` has retained *all* the levels from the original df.

What would be the recommended way to drop the unused level(s), i.e. `"fall"` and `"others"`, within the `dplyr` framework?

Comment: I have been using spreadsheets quite a lot for data pre-processing, but since I discovered `dplyr` that seems to have changed ;-) However, when one applies filters in a spreadsheet, the "hidden" range seems to be nonexistent for copy/paste operations. That's why I was surprised finding the filtered content partially transferred to the new df after applying `filter()`. Therefore I asked how to get the same effect *within* the `dplyr` framework, expecting that there might be an argument for that.

Comment: Would it be OK to entirely delete this question now?

Comment: If it will declutter the environment I'll do so gladly. Hope that both helpers won't mind the downvote...

Comment: I think they will...

Comment: It seems that I can't downvote until the answers are edited :-/

Comment: Just leave it as is. The answers show some additional implementation on `dplyr`

Comment: My understanding is that duplicate questions should be _closed_, not necessarily deleted because they might help others find the original question and answers in the future.

Answer (score 55):

You could do something like:

```
dat1 <- dat0 %>%
  filter(s == "spring") %>% 
  droplevels()
```

Then

```
str(df)
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ f: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
# $ s: Factor w/ 1 level "spring": 1
# $ v: num 5
```

Comment: Thanks! That seems quite a logical approach.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `droplevels`

```
 sp.tmp <- droplevels(sp.tmp)
 str(sp.tmp)
 #'data.frame': 1 obs. of  3 variables:
 #$ f: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
 #$ s: Factor w/ 1 level "spring": 1
# $ v: num 5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Isn't there a way to do this *while* `filter()`ing?

Comment: @ils I guess `filter` does not have an argument to drop the levels (to my knowledge).