# R Droplevels Function Fail With Factor

Tags: r

My dataframe named 'data' contains a variable named 'income' with 26 levels. I want to delete or drop the level 'Refused' so there are only 25 levels.

Below is a truncated printout of the levels. See number 26 'Refused':

```
> levels(data$income)
[1] "Under $1 000"       "$1 000 To 2 999"    "$3 000 To 3 999"
And so on...
[25] "$150000 Or Over"    "Refused"
```

I researched the `droplevels` function and tried this:

```
data <- droplevels(income$Refused)
```

This:

```
droplevels(data, income$Refused)
```

And even this:

```
data %<>% droplevels(income$Refused)
```

I think the problem may be that the class is factor. The documentation on `droplevels` isn't that easy to decipher.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`droplevels()` only drops those values not in use; you can't use it to drop explicit levels. If you want to drop all rows with "Refused" and drop the levels from the factor, then use this

```
droplevels(subset(data, income!="Refused"))
```

Comment: In the end I incorporated your suggestion in a dplyr `filter`. So:

`filter(income !='Refused') %>%`. 

Not as clean a solution as I'd hoped for, but does the trick.

Comment: @Jonathan, usage in a dplyr pipe is also described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26826956/3521006)

Comment: @docendodiscimus, This is useful. Much more explicit in accordance with the aim of dropping a level. Will use in future.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could think of dropping a specific level would be to kill the level, leaving `NA` values instead of the original level. E.g.:

```
dat <- data.frame(income=factor(c("a","b","c")))
dat$income
#[1] a b c
#Levels: a b c
factor(as.character(dat$income),levels=setdiff(levels(dat$income),"a"))
#[1] <NA> b    c   
#Levels: b c
```