# data.frame using raw data instead of filtered data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have got that issue I can't my head around:

```
library(dplyr)

d<-data.frame(c1=c("a","a","b","b"),c2=c(1,1,3,4))

dFiltered <-  d %>%
  filter(c1 == "a") %>%
  select(c1)

> dFiltered
  c1
1  a
2  a
```

so then I want to create a data.frame to get the frequency of c1 based on the filtered data

```
> data.frame(table(dFiltered))
  dFiltered Freq
1         a    2
2         b    0
```

I don't understand why the value b appears as well even though it shows 0, I don't expect to find it here because if I run the same but selecting a value from c2

```
> dFiltered <-  d %>%
   filter(c2 == "1") %>%
   select(c2)
> data.frame(table(dFiltered))
```

then I get what I expect

```
  dFiltered Freq
1         1    2
```

I am sure there is a rational explanation to this

Comment: Because its a factor. See `?droplevels` Or just do `d %>% filter(c1 == "a") %>% count(c1)`. Btw, `dplyr` isn't base R.

Comment: and also of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826865/how-to-drop-unused-levels-after-filtering-by-factor)

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, why does it matter that dplyr is not a base R?

Comment: It's just when you creating a reproducible example you should add `library(dplyr)` as it isn't being exported with base R

Comment: I will make sure I do. Thanks guys