# dplyr: Find date for which an event occurs

Tags: r, dplyr

First question. I am fairly new at R. I have the following data frame.

```
Source: local data frame [865,264 x 10]

   page_views       date dayofweek daytype   caseID dateDecision dateArgument dateRearg
1         169 2008-01-30 Wednesday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
2         211 2008-01-16 Wednesday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
3         203 2008-01-17  Thursday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
4         177 2008-01-14    Monday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
5         224 2008-01-15   Tuesday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
6         152 2008-01-12  Saturday       1 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
7         149 2008-01-13    Sunday       1 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
8         220 2008-01-10  Thursday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
9         169 2008-01-11    Friday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
10        189 2008-01-18    Friday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01          
..        ...        ...       ...     ...      ...          ...          ...       ...
Variables not shown: caseName (chr), term (int)
```

I would like to find the first, earliest chronologically, date for each caseID for which page_views is greater than zero. I would like to create a new column with this date. The results should have one row for each caseID.

I am hoping that I can do this using dplyr, but I am open to other solutions. Using dplyr it seems group_by(caseID) and some kind of filter are the place to start, but I have had no luck.

I have searched stackoverflow and other places and haven't found anything that comes close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With dplyr you can do this almost as it is written in your description.

```
x %>% group_by(caseID) %>% filter(page_views > 0) %>%
      arrange(date) %>% summarise(min_date=head(date,1))
```

Comment: This solution did exactly what I was asking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**If you want to create a new summary table:**

```
df %>%
  filter (page_views > 0) %>%
  group_by (caseID) %>%
  summarise (earliestDate = min(date))
```

The `date` variable cannot be a factor for `min` to work; it can be a character, though.

*Output*:

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

    caseID earliestDate
1 2007-001   2008-01-10
```

You can replace the last line of the above code with   `filter (min_rank(date) == 1)` to produce the same result.

**If you simply want to de-duplicate the table you have now:**

```
df %>%
  filter (page_views > 0) %>%
  group_by (caseID) %>%
  arrange (date) %>%
  slice(1) # takes the first row, which will be the earliest since the table is sorted by date
```

*Output*:

```
Source: local data frame [1 x 8]
Groups: caseID

  row page_views       date dayofweek daytype   caseID dateDecision dateArgument
1   8        220 2008-01-10  Thursday       0 2007-001   2007-10-10   2007-10-01
```

**Edit:** This is a slightly more elegant way to create this same subset:

```
df %>% group_by(caseID) %>%
  filter(page_views > 0, date == min(date))
```

Comment: For the second option: you can drop the arrange call and use slice(which.min(date)) instead (more concise and likely faster as well). A related question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308436

Comment: @docendodiscimus: I found this related question, but couldn't get it to work property. Thanks.

Comment: The solutions posed here don't quite, work and I am not sure why. The first solution does not produce a date for each caseID. There are many NAs. The second produces a list of the first date for each caseID. The dataset is rectangular so some of the first dates do not have any search activity. (I didn't include that in the description of the problem, but should have. Slice was new to me, thanks.  I added a line from the proposed solution below and it worked.  
df2 <- orig_df %>%
  filter (page_views > 0) %>%
  group_by (caseID) %>%
  arrange (date) %>%
  slice(1)

Comment: I wonder why the first solution didn't work for you - must be some aspect of the data that's not present in the sample you posted.  And good catch that `filter()` was missing from the second solution; I've updated the answer to add that.  Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a possible `data.table` one liner. You can simultaniously filter by `page_views > 0L` in the `i` expression, find the `min(date)` in the `j` expression while aggregating by `caseID` in the `by` expression

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[page_views > 0L, min(date), caseID]
#      caseID         V1
# 1: 2007-001 2008-01-10
```

Or if you want all the columns, you can use **S**ub**D**ata (`.SD`) as in

```
setDT(df)[page_views > 0L, .SD[which.min(date)], caseID]
#      caseID page_views       date dayofweek daytype dateDecision dateArgument
# 1: 2007-001        220 2008-01-10  Thursday       0   2007-10-10   2007-10-01
```