# How to find the distinct of one column based on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, r, groupwise-maximum

I have a data frame like below

```
col1    col2    col3
A       Z       10
A       Y       8
A       Z       15
B       X       11
B       Z       7
C       Y       10
D       Z       11
D       Y       14
D       L       16
```

I have to select, for each `distinct col1` which of the `col2` have `max(col3)`

Output data frame should look like,

```
col1    col2    col3
A       Z       15
B       X       11
C       Y       10
D       L       16
```

How to do this either in `R` or in `SQL`

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you want to handle ties?

Comment: Also `library(data.table) ; unique(setorder(setDT(df), -col3), by = "col1")`, though as mentioned, it's not clear how you want to handle ties.

Comment: For a dplyr approach that only returns a sinlge row per group (also in case of ties), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308436

Comment: @docendo-discimus: There is no ties 95%, remaining, as long as any one comes, its fine.

Comment: @DavidArenburg: Thanks for your solution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'col1', we subset the data.table (`.SD`) based on the index of max value of 'col3'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[which.max(col3)], col1]
#     col1 col2 col3
#1:    A    Z   15
#2:    B    X   11
#3:    C    Y   10
#4:    D    L   16
```

---

Or we can use `top_n` from `dplyr` after grouping by 'col1'.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
      group_by(col1) %>%
      top_n(1)
```

Comment: Many thanks for quick response. :) Its not allowing to accept your answer as quick as you answered.

Comment: @ManojG Thanks for the feedback.  I think it will take some 10 mins or so.

Comment: Your solutions in dplyr and data.table will differ in case of ties. Just saying

Comment: @akrun: I applied data.table solution in a data frame consists of about `7million` rows out of which it had, around `4.7 million unique col1` but the output I got is `1.5 million rows`. Any idea what would have went wrong?

Comment: @ManojG  It is strange.  Are you getting `length(unique(df1$col1))` as 4.7 million.  Do you have unique col1 with only missing values?

Comment: @akrun: No missing values. Data is clean. `col1` & `col2` are numbers which has more than 10 digits. so it was storing as `e+`. After i converted both in to characters and ran, its fine. But it is super slow. I think `data.table` is slower with characters!

Comment: @ManojG I think you can load `library(bit64)` and then read the dataset using `?fread` from `data.table`.  The column would be to converted to `integer64` class.

Comment: @akrun: Thank you! I'll try this out :)

Answer (score 3):

SQL answer:

Use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same col1 value that has a higher col3 value.

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.col1 = t1.col1
                    and t2.col3 > t1.col3)
```

Will return both rows for a col1 if there's a max(c3) tie.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing in MySQL.

Here is the [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d631f/1)

**Output** : =>[image]

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM
table_name T1
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT col1,MAX(col3) AS Max_col3 FROM table_name GROUP BY col1) T2 
            ON T1.`col1` = T2.`col1` and T2.`Max_col3`=t1.`col3`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you remove col2 from the sub-query, your answer will be ANSI SQL compliant and portable!

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode: Thanks for your solution, but in case of ties, it would give multiple rows na!

Comment: Yeah it will return multiple row. What to do,when there is tie?We can do accordinly to ur requiremnet.

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode If ties, I need any one row out of it irrespective of which row it is.