# find value closest to x by group in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
a <- data_frame(id = c("A","A","A","B","B","B"),
                b = c(1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 1.1, 1.6, 1.4))
```

Now, I´d like to retrieve the values closest to 1.43 for each of the catergories in id. 
I thought I could use:

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% nth(which.min(abs(.$b-1.43)))
```

but dplyr states

```
Error: Don't know how to generate default for object of class grouped_df/tbl_df/tbl/data.frame
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`which.min()` returns the *index of the (first) minimum or maximum of a numeric (or logical) vector.* If there are multiple equal values as close to 1.43 as each other and you want to keep all of them, you can use `filter()`:

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(abs(b - 1.43) == min(abs(b - 1.43)))

#Source: local data frame [2 x 2]
#Groups: id [2]

#     id     b
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1     A   1.5
#2     B   1.4
```

---

If you prefer sticking with the `nth()` function, and it is OK to have only one value for each group, you can wrap it within a summarize function so that it will be applied to each group, and also according to `?nth()`, you need to pass the vector to the function as an argument as well:

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(b = nth(b, which.min(abs(b-1.43))))

# A tibble: 2 × 2
#     id     b
#  <chr> <dbl>
#1     A   1.5
#2     B   1.4
```

Answer (score 12):

There are a few ways to do this.

Here's a `dplyr` solution (found using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23758886/5619526)):

```
a %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    slice(which.min(abs(b - 1.43)))

     id     b
  <chr> <dbl>
1     A   1.5
2     B   1.4
```

Here's a base solution:

```
do.call('rbind', by(a, a$id, function(x) x[which.min(abs(x$b - 1.43)), ]))

     id     b
  <chr> <dbl>
1     A   1.5
2     B   1.4
```

Here's a hacky `dplyr` solution:

```
a %>%
    mutate(AbsDiff = abs(b - 1.43)) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(AbsDiff_r = rank(AbsDiff, ties.method = 'first')) %>%
    filter(AbsDiff_r == 1)

     id     b AbsDiff AbsDiff_r
  <chr> <dbl>   <dbl>     <int>
1     A   1.5    0.07         1
2     B   1.4    0.03         1
```

Comment: If you want to avoid the `do.call(rbind...` for the base version, you can also do: `a[by(a, a$id, FUN=function(SD) rownames(SD)[which.min(abs(SD$b - 1.43))] ),]`

Comment: Love the dplyr `slice`!

Answer (score 5):

Not too far from what you had

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(which.min(abs(b-1.43)))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#      id `which.min(abs(b - 1.43))`
#   <chr>                      <int>
# 1     A                          2
# 2     B                          3
```

Or if you need the values, rather than the indices:

```
a %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(b[which.min(abs(b-1.43))])
# A tibble: 2 × 2
#      id `b[which.min(abs(b - 1.43))]`
#   <chr>                         <dbl>
# 1     A                           1.5
# 2     B                           1.4
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a version with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .(b= b[which.min(abs(b-1.43))]) , id]
#  id   b
#1:  A 1.5
#2:  B 1.4
```