# Selecting rows with "closest" values in each subgroup using dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, purrr

I'am just learning R and I try to find a way to select rows from a `data.frame`

I would like to select for every `ID` one row for each group `"pre"` and `post` which has the smalles difference in `abs(d_days`), i.e have a similar interval pre-ref, ref-post. The minimum difference should be 1 year.

I am not looking for a maximum or minimum difference, but for the closest/nearest/ most similar difference > 1 year.

### my test data.frame looks like:

```
"ID"      "date"      "d_days" "group"
"00377698" 2006-11-15 -1006   "pre"
"00377698" 2009-08-16 -1      "pre"
"00377698" 2009-08-17 0       "ref"
"00377698" 2009-08-24 7      "post"
"00377698" 2009-09-03 17     "post"
"00377698" 2009-10-09 53     "post"
"00377698" 2010-02-26 193    "post"
"00377698" 2010-08-27 375    "post"
"00377698" 2010-11-26 466    "post"
"00377698" 2011-08-24 737    "post"
"00540688" 2009-06-26 -1664  "pre"
"00540688" 2009-08-20 -1609  "pre"
"00540688" 2009-11-20 -1517  "pre"
"00540688" 2010-11-17 -1155  "pre"
"00540688" 2011-12-07 -770   "pre"
"00540688" 2014-01-09 -6     "pre"
"00540688" 2014-01-15 0      "ref"
"00540688" 2014-01-20 5      "post"
"00540688" 2014-03-05 49     "post"
"00540688" 2015-04-29 469    "post"
"00540688" 2015-09-30 623    "post"
"00540688" 2016-05-13 849    "post"
```

### my attempts:

I tried somethinkg like `data.frame %>% group_by(ID,group) %>% filter (group=="pre"| group=="post" & abs(d_days > 365)) %>% summarise(b = nth(abs(d_days[1]), which.max(abs(d_days[2]))))`

I also tried `roll=nearest` [R - merge dataframes on matching A, B and *closest* C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16095680/r-merge-dataframes-on-matching-a-b-and-closest-c)

I also tried this [find value closest to x by group in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40835543/find-value-closest-to-x-by-group-in-dplyr), but it did not work out since I am not looking for values close to a specific value but just the "closest" of two sub-groups.

### Unfortunately, I could not get what I am looking for:

```
"ID"      "date"      "d_days" "group"
"00377698" 2006-11-15 -1006   "pre"
"00377698" 2009-08-17 0       "ref"
"00377698" 2011-08-24 737    "post"
"00540688" 2011-12-07 -770   "pre"
"00540688" 2014-01-15 0      "ref"
"00540688" 2015-09-30 894    "post"
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm a little confused about your requirements, are you only looking for "pre" and "post" groups that are >365 like in your attempts?  I have something like `df %>%
  group_by(ID, group) %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>% 
  filter(abs(d_days) > 365) %>%
  mutate(range = as.Date(date)-lag(as.Date(date),1))`

Comment: @ Geochem, many thanks for your answer. I am looking for "pre" and "post" groups that are >365 and that have the closest time interval (e.g. from all "pre's" and "post's" with the ID 00540688 the closest interval are 770 and 894.

Comment: Why is the "ref" in your example of the final solution?  Are you looking for the closest value to "ref" since it is between the two ID's in this case?

Comment: I added the ref in my solution just to illustrate my data. It is not really needed. I am not looking for the closest value to "ref", I am only looking for "similar" time intervals between pre-ref and ref-post that are > 365 days.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my best shot getting values close to 0 which would fufills half of the issue.  Close but not complete.

```
df %>%
  filter(group != "ref",
         abs(d_days) > 365) %>% 
  group_by(ID, group) %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  filter(abs(d_days - 0) == min(abs(d_days - 0)))

      ID       date d_days  group
   <int>     <fctr>  <int> <fctr>
1 377698 2006-11-15  -1006    pre
2 377698 2010-08-27    375   post
3 540688 2011-12-07   -770    pre
4 540688 2015-04-29    469   post
```