# Find nearest entry between dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, match, tidyverse

I have two dataframes that I want to compare. I already know that the values in dataframe one (df1$BP) are not within the range of values in dataframe two (df2$START and df2$STOP), but I want to return the row in dataframe two where df2$START or df2$STOP is closest in value to df1$BP, where the "Chr" column matches between datasets (df1$Chr, df2$Chr).

I **have** managed to do this (see bottom of Q), but it seems SERIOUSLY unwieldy, and I wondered if there was a more parsimonious manner of achieving the same thing.

So for dataframe one (df1), we have:

```
 df1=data.frame(SNP=c("rs79247094","rs13325007"),
           Chr=c(2,3),
           BP=c(48554955,107916058))
```

> df1

```
SNP         Chr    BP
rs79247094    2     48554955
rs13325007    3    107916058
```

For dataframe two, we have:

```
 df2=data.frame(clump=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
           Chr=c(2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
           START=c(28033538,37576136,58143438,60389362,80814042,107379837,136288405,161777035),
           STOP=c(27451538,36998607,57845065,60242162,79814042,107118837,135530405,161092491))
```

> df2

```
 Clump    Chr      START       STOP
     1      2   28033538   27451538
     2      2   37576136   36998607
     3      2   58143438   57845065
     4      2   60389362   60242162
     5      3   80814042   79814042
     6      3  107379837  107118837
     7      3  136288405  135530405
     8      3  161777035  161092491
```

I am interested in returning which START/STOP values are closest to BP. Ideally, I could return the row, and what the difference between BP and START or STOP is (df3$Dist), like:

> df3

```
 Clump   Chr      START       STOP         SNP        BP       Dist
     3     2   58143438   57845065  rs79247094  48554955    9290110
     6     3  107379837  107118837  rs13325007  107916058    536221
```

I have found **similar** questions, for example: [Return rows establishing a "closest value to" in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41496276/return-rows-establishing-a-closest-value-to-in-r)

But these are finding the closest values based on a fixed value, rather than a value that changes (and matching on the Chr column).

My long winded method is:

```
df3<-right_join(df1,df2,by="Chr")
```

to give me all of the combinations of df1 and df2 together.

```
df3$start_dist<-abs(df3$START-df3$BP)
```

to create a column with the absolute difference between START and BP

```
df3$stop_dist<-abs(df3$STOP-df3$BP)
```

to create a column with the absolute difference between STOP and BP

```
df3$dist.compare<-ifelse(df3$start_dist<df3$stop_dist,df3$start_dist,df3$stop_dist)
df3<-df3[with(df3,order(SNP,"dist.compare")),]
```

to create a column (dist.compare) which prints the smallest difference between BP and START or STOP (and the re-order by that column)

```
df3<- df3 %>%   group_by(SNP) %>%   mutate(Dist = first(dist.compare))
```

to create a column (Dist) which prints the minimum value from df3$dist.compare

```
df3<-df3[which(df3$dist.compare==df3$Dist),c("clump","Chr","START","STOP","SNP","BP","Dist")]
df3<-df3[order(df3$clump),]
```

to only print rows where dist.compare matches Dist (so the minimum value), and drop the intermediate columns, and tidy up by re-ordering by clump. Now that gets me to where I want to be:

> df3

```
 Clump   Chr      START       STOP         SNP        BP       Dist
     3     2   58143438   57845065  rs79247094  48554955    9290110
     6     3  107379837  107118837  rs13325007  107916058    536221
```

But I feel like it is very very convoluted, and wondered if anyone had any tips on how to refine that process?

thanks in advance

Comment: I am not on my desktop so I can't propose a full syntax, but I would have done it like this - pivot_longer the start and stop cols from df2 then left_join it with df1 then find distance and lastly filter for min distance group_by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the logic you've laid out in your syntax, here is a `dplyr` solution that is a bit cleaner:

1. `right_join` your dataframes
2. Create a variable `dist.compare` based on absolute values
3. Group by `SNP`
4. Filter to keep the smallest distance
5. Select variables in the order you'd like for your final dataframe. Note you can rename variables in a `dplyr::select` statement (`Dist = dist.compare`)
6. Order values by `clump`

   ```
    library(dplyr)

    df3 <- right_join(df1, df2, by = "Chr") %>% 
      mutate(dist.compare = ifelse(abs(START - BP) < abs(STOP - BP), abs(START - BP), abs(STOP - BP))) %>% 
      group_by(SNP) %>% 
      filter(dist.compare == min(dist.compare)) %>% 
      select(clump, Chr, START, STOP, SNP, BP, Dist = dist.compare) %>% 
      arrange(clump)
   ```

This gives us:

```
  clump   Chr     START      STOP SNP               BP    Dist
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>   <dbl>
1     3     2  58143438  57845065 rs79247094  48554955 9290110
2     6     3 107379837 107118837 rs13325007 107916058  536221
```

Comment: This is the level of clean and pristine beauty that I was striving to achieve, rather than the lengthy prose I had managed!! Thank you so much. This will really help me with future dplyr endeavours :)

Comment: No problem - happy to help!