# How to count subsets of elements in an data frame using base R or dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, subset

I would like to add a column to the below data frame `nCode`, call the desired new column "`grpRnk`", that counts each group's rank (a group defined as `Group` value <> 0) among the other groups in the dataframe, with the top rank defined as the lowest associated `nmCnt` for that grouped row and then descending rank from there as the `nmCnt` increases for the other grouped rows. As described in the column manually added ("**grpRnk ADD**") to the far right in the data frame output below:

```
> print.data.frame(nCode)
  Name Group nmCnt seqBase subGrp  grpRnk ADD
1    B     0     1       1      0    0 since Group = 0
2    R     0     1       1      0    0 since Group = 0
3    R     1     2       2      1    2 since it is 2nd place among the Groups, with its nmCnt > the nmCnt for the highest ranking Group in row 6
4    R     1     3       2      2    2 same reason as above
5    B     0     2       2      0    0 since Group = 0
6    X     2     1       1      1    1 since it is 1st place among the Groups, with its nmCnt of 1 is the lowest among all the groups
7    X     2     2       1      2    1 same reason as above
```

Any recommendations for how to do this in base R or dplyr?

Below is the code that generates the above (except for the column manually added on the right):

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

myDF5 <- 
  data.frame(
    Name = c("B","R","R","R","B","X","X"),
    Group = c(0,0,1,1,0,2,2)
  )

nCode <-  myDF5 %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  mutate(nmCnt = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(seqBase = ifelse(Group == 0 | Group != lag(Group), nmCnt,0)) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = na_if(seqBase, 0)) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  fill(seqBase) %>%
  mutate(seqBase = match(seqBase, unique(seqBase))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(subGrp = as.integer(ifelse(Group > 0, sapply(1:n(), function(x) sum(Name[1:x]==Name[x] & Group[1:x] == Group[x])),0)))

print.data.frame(nCode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a dplyr solution. However instead of filling non-groups with 0 per my OP, this code drops in NA for non-groups which works better for me for what this is intended for. The dplyr `slice()` function used in my solution is new to me and is very useful, I found out about it in post [dplyr filter: Get rows with minimum of variable, but only the first if multiple minima](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308436/dplyr-filter-get-rows-with-minimum-of-variable-but-only-the-first-if-multiple)

```
grpRnk <- nCode %>% select(Name,Group,nmCnt) %>% 
  filter(Group > 0) %>% 
  group_by(Name) %>% 
  slice(which.min(Group)) %>% 
  arrange(nmCnt) %>%
  select(-nmCnt)
grpRnk$grpRnk <- as.integer(row.names(grpRnk)) 
left_join(nCode,grpRnk)
```